# iPhone SDK, reading GPS co-ords from LocationManager

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps

I've got the following code in my main .m file (I want to send the gps co-ords in a http query string)

```
- (CLLocationManager *)locationManager {

    if (locationManager != nil) {
        return locationManager;
    }

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;

    return locationManager;
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager  didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation  fromLocation:(CLLocation *) oldLocation {


    NSString *latitudeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g°", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSLog(@"lat is %@", latitudeString);
    //self.myLatitude = latitudeString;
    [latitudeString release];

    NSString *longitudeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g°", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    NSLog(@"long is %@", longitudeString);
    //self.myLongitude = longitudeString;
    [longitudeString release];

}
```

And in my .h I have:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {    

    CLLocationManager *locationManager;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;


@end
```

(i've stripped out the unnecessary lines in the .h)

How can I use the current GPS long/lat from above in a different block of code: (substituting the LONGVAR/LATVAR)

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *tempvariable;
    NSString *gpsLat;



    switch (indexPath.row) {

        case 0:
            tempvariable = @"http://randomurl.randomurl.com/mobilesearch/what/Hotels%20and%20Inns/0/0/0/UK/**LONGVAR/LATVAR**/0/0/342/0/0/0/0/0/search.aspx";
            break;
        case 1:
           tempvariable = (@"http://randomurl.randomurl.com/mobilesearch/what/Public%20Houses/0/0/0/UK/**LONGVAR/LATVAR**/0/0/505/0/0/0/0/0/search.aspx");
            break;
        case 2:
            tempvariable = (@"http://randomurl.randomurl.com/mobilesearch/what/All%20Restaurants/0/0/0/UK/**LONGVAR/LATVAR**/0/0/527/0/0/0/0/0/search.aspx");
            break;
        case 3:
            tempvariable = (@"http://randomurl.randomurl.com/mobilesearch/what/Health Care/0/0/0/UK/**LONGVAR/LATVAR**/0/0/843/0/0/0/0/0/search.aspx");
            break;
        default:
            tempvariable = (@"http://randomurl.randomurl.com/mobilesearch/what/Hotels and Inns/0/0/0/UK/**LONGVAR/LATVAR/**0/0/342/0/0/0/0/0/search.aspx");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe i'm missing something but just store newLocation.coordinate.latitude in some float value that you define in header..

you can have a singletone class if you need it across the application, or store it to nsuserdefaults..

Comment: Hi @paxx thanks for that. I did try that, I had this in my header 
 `CLLocationDegrees *gpsLat;`

and in the class this:
`gpsLat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;`

But i get an error about asigning a CLLocationDegrees to a CLLocationDegrees

Comment: just remove * from CLLocationDegrees.. do it like this `CLLocationDegrees gpsLat`. And that should be it. Reason for not using * is because CLLocationDegrees is a structure and not object. You can use cmd key + double click on a variable and it will lead you to definition.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've set the variable (as far as i'm aware) but it's not sending it through, how do I call the routine to run, as obviously nothing is setting `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager  didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation  fromLocation:(CLLocation *) oldLocation {` in the viewDidLoad, or does it run automatically?

Comment: you have to test it on device.. simulator does not simulate location updates.. on simulator you should always get a fail.. delegate method `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` is the one in which you should handle error on update..